# How to get a record depending of an other record without CTE and UNION

Tags: sql-server, performance, common-table-expression

I need to extract a record from my cost table and I need to have a generic record only if the one with a specific value is not found. I have that simplified query that work and basicly do what I want.

```
WITH BaseCost AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table1 
    WHERE Val1 = 'SomeValue'
          AND Val2 = 'OtherValue')
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 seq ,*
    FROM BaseCost WHERE Val3 = 'MyValue'
    UNION
    SELECT 2 seq ,*
    FROM BaseCost WHERE Val3 = '*')QRY
ORDER BY QRY.seq
```

I was wondering, is there a better way to achive that than create a CTE, UNION records to take only the first one? This query will be run quite often, I'd like to have it as fast as possible.

Comment: As you only take one row `UNION ALL` will be a bit faster.

Comment: Well you can happily use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` since there is no need to filter out duplicates.

Comment: Remove Select * (just select fields you need), that is good practice no matter what you are doing.

Comment: Why not just `SELECT TOP 1 <cols> FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Val1 = 'SomeValue' AND Val2 = 'OtherValue' AND Val3 IN ('MyValue', '*') ORDER BY CASE WHEN Val3 = 'MyValue' THEN 1 WHEN Val3 = '*' THEN 2 END;`? How fast it will be will depend on whether you've invested in the right index to satisfy the query.

Comment: did not get why you `ORDER BY QRY.seq` and why do not combine `Val3 = ..` with the CTE query, like `Val3 IN (..)`

Comment: @Brad, I totally agree with you, I didn't what to have a sample to big for nothing but my real query only contain required fields ;)

Comment: Ok, cool, just want to make sure

Comment: @lad2025, I didn't thought of that but it's logical. In my dev environment, it does nothing different, I'll try in prod.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I will try it in my prod environment, in dev, the execution plan is a little bit slower but the query look a lot nicer to look at ;)

Comment: @LONG, it's to confirm that I have to right one, I was not sure if SQL Server would always gave me the same result without it. For the filter in the CTE, I added it, it's a little bit faster (on the execution plan, I wouldn't notice the difference ;)

Answer (score 0):

With all the recommendations, this is what is faster on my 200K records table (not that much for now but getting bigger every day)

```
WITH BaseCost AS (
    SELECT Val1, Val2, Val3, OtherVal
    FROM dbo.Table1 
    WHERE Val1 = 'SomeValue'
          AND Val2 = 'OtherValue'
          AND Val3 IN ('MyValue', '*'))
SELECT TOP 1 Val1, Val2, Val3, OtherVal
FROM (
    SELECT 1 seq ,Val1, Val2, Val3, OtherVal
    FROM BaseCost WHERE Val3 = 'MyValue'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 seq ,Val1, Val2, Val3, OtherVal
    FROM BaseCost WHERE Val3 = '*')QRY
ORDER BY QRY.seq
```

I really liked the idea of the `ORDER BY CASE WHEN` but it's slower than the actual query, since I need fast executions, I can't use that even if it's more readable.

Comment: Have you tried writing your CTE to a temp table to see if it improves performance?

Comment: Just tried it and it's a little bit slower that the ORDER BY CASE WHEN

Comment: how about writing it to a table variable?

Comment: It's basicly the same in the execution plan for the job I have to do with it.